# Does Windows 7 Support Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, hyper-v

Now that Windows 7 Enterprise is available for VLK Users to download, I would like to check it out.  The only thing holding me back is that I am an application developer (currently developing on a Windows Server 2008 installation) and the most useful thing I use is Hyper-V to create VMs of the systems I would like to test on.

Is it possible to run Hyper-V under Windows 7 Enterprise? Or am I stuck with Windows Server 2008?

Comment: Similar question on Server Fault:  http://serverfault.com/questions/9274/hyper-v-on-windows-7

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately that seems to be the case:

> System requirements / Specifications
>
> - An x64-based processor running an x64 version of Windows Server 2008
>     Standard, Windows Server 2008
>     Enterprise or Windows Server 2008
>     Datacenter.

[Hyper-V System Requirements and Specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V#System_requirements_.2F_Specifications)

---

Credits to [Diago](https://superuser.com/users/3981/diago):

The alternative to Hyper-V for Windows 7 is Virtual PC for Windows 7 available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx). It is currently in RC but will be available soon. It also requires hardware assisted virtualization to work.

If you want 64-Bit VM's however you will have to load Windows Server 2008 and load Hyper-V since Virtual PC does not support this.

For 64-Bit [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) or [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/) are good options.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 runs fine on Hyper-V, Hyper-V does not run on Windows 7.

As other people have said, you can use Microsoft Virtual PC or Vmware Workstation along with a whole load of other VM software.

Comment: VirtualBox or VMware*

Answer (score 0):

You are stuck with Windows Server 2008 if you have to use Hyper-V. You can always switch to another virtualization software like VMware or VirtualPC or you can wait until Server 2008 R2 is released, which is the server version of Windows 7.

Comment: FYI. R2 is available on MSDN already.