# Moving Windows 10 Hyper-V machine to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hyper-v

Can a Hyper-V virtual machine (running 64-bit Ubuntu Desktop) be moved to a computer running Windows 7 Hyper-V? Are there any compatibility issues?

Comment: Not possible, because Windows 7 can not run Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1):

First up, you can't install Hyper-V on Windows 7, only the Hyper-V Manager.

If you only have Windows 8, you will also have trouble if the VM is Generation 2, since that was introduced in Windows Server 2012 R2 (Windows 8.1). It will almost certainly have its hard disk in VHDX format, which is not supported on the version of Hyper-V that can be installed on Windows 8. You'll need to [convert the VHDX to VHD](https://blog.bertvanlangen.com/articles/convert-vhdx-vhd/) *on your Windows 10 machine*. You would then move the VHD to the Windows 8 host and create a new VM from it.

If the new host is Windows 8.1, though, you should just be able to copy the VHDX and create a new Generation 2 machine.

Comment: According to many sources on the web, Windows 7 cannot run Hyper-V at all. For example [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/29575/does-windows-7-support-hyper-v)

Comment: Ah, you are right. I found instructions on installing the Hyper-V *Manager* on Windows 7 and assumed that it also installed Hyper-V. My mistake; I've updated my answer.